Efficiency of ratios
Suppose we have a computer application and we want to calculate the influence of the frequency in the final runtime.
If this application is executed at 2 GHz this takes 1000s, whereas if the application is run at 3 GHz it only takes 860s.
I usually do something like:
a) ((1000 - 860)/1000) / ((3 - 2)/3)  = 42%
However, I have also seen this calculated in a different way:
b) ((1000 - 860) / 860) / ((3 - 2)/2)) = 32%
I am finding very hard to understand the meaning of calculating the depencency of the frequency in one way or the other.
What would be the right way? What is the meaning of the a) and b) percentages?

Both formulas are approximations for a logarithmic derivative. If the differences become really small, say from 2 Ghz to 2.05 Ghz and from 1000s to 998s, then the two definitions give nearly the same result. The logarithmic derivative of a function $f$ (execution time) with respect to $x$ (clock frequency) is
$$\frac{d\log f(x)}{d\log x}=\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}$$
It has the advantage of being independent of the units chosen for either the dependent or the independent variable, e.g., the result would not change if you expressed the frequency in rpm and the execution time in weeks.
